# Critical System Issue

Tags: graphic-drivers, pantheon-terminal, shell

Since attempting to install Steam and receiving the error message that there are apparently "held packages" on my system, I attempted to start my computer today and it repeatedly fails to load the OS. I also cannot boot to other media such as a CD/DVD or USB drive. I am stuck with a console interface of the operating system and I don't know how to get my main graphical interface back.

Comment: Then, after dozens of reboots, magically I was able to boot using the disk drive and reinstalled the OS. It sure would be nice to know what was going on and why things mysteriously change despite no explicit changes being made.

Answer (score 1):

You messed up some dependencies by holding packages .

(I know that libstdc++ issue with steam and that there's a solution where you actually have to hold-mark certain packages, but you can definately fry your system with that. Also, you only have to delete a few library files in the steam folder to get it running, and if you ask a new quesion, I'm pleased to go more detailed about this.)

And you most likely uninstalled X and pantheon, the desktop environment of elementary OS. That way you will always see the command prompt when booting, since you deleted everything else. ;)